# create multiple text attributes for single class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, uifont

I am new to programming and am trying to create a single class that will set the size, attribute, color and align text center as I am using the below code. I am trying to do a bit more, but can modify once i know how to setup that one class.

Any help, please.

```
@implementation OceansTabController
@synthesize textField;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.textField.text = @"\"The sea, once it casts its spell, holds one in its net of wonder forever.\"\nJacques Yves Cousteau\n\nOur majestic oceans\n\n";

    NSMutableAttributedString *attString=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:textField.text];
    //
    //    UIFont *font_regular=[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14.0f];

    UIFont *font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14.0f];
    UIFont *font_italic=[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Italic" size:14.0f];
    UIFont *font_bold=[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:14.0f];
    UIFont *font_boldBlue=[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:14.0f];
    UIFont *font_boldLarge=[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:16.0f];
    UIFont *font_boldLargeCentered=[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:16.0f];

[attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font_italic range:NSMakeRange(0, 75)];
[attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font_boldBlue range:NSMakeRange(76, 21)];
[attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font_boldLargeCentered range:NSMakeRange(98, 20)];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shubham bairagi, thanks for your help.  Reading this again, i do realize i was not fully clear on what i wanted as the issue is i don't know all of the terms, to ask properly.  Anyway, I found the solution:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attString=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:textField.text];
//
//    UIFont *font_regular=[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14.0f];

UIFont *font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14.0f];
UIFont *font_italic=[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Italic" size:14.0f];
UIFont *font_bold=[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:14.0f];
UIFont *font_boldLarge=[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:16.0f];
```

The above is the same as what i posted, but I added this line to set the color I wanted

```
UIColor *blueColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

That set the variable (hoping i used the correct term)

Then I added the variable to the below code.  You will notice that i added one extra line with the same range. That gave me two lines of code with the same range (blue and bold).  However, I found that instead of using NSFontAttributeName, I used NSForegroundColorAttributeName to set the color.

```
[attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font_italic range:NSMakeRange(0, 138)];
[attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font_bold range:NSMakeRange(139, 21)];
[attString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:blueColor range:NSMakeRange(139, 21)];
[attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font_boldLarge range:NSMakeRange(161, 35)];
```

If I am not clear, let me know and I will try again.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a subclass of uitextfield . where you can define method for setting attributes as shown below

in customTextField.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface customtextField : UITextField

- (void)setCustomTextFieldText:(NSString*)text;

- (void)setCustomTextFieldAttributes;

@end
```

and in customTextField.m

you can define fonts or any property as mecros

```
#import "customtextField.h"

#define font [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14.0f]
#define font_italic [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Italic" size:14.0f]
#define font_bold [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:14.0f]
#define font_boldBlue [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:14.0f]
#define font_boldLarge [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:16.0f]
#define font_boldLargeCentered [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:16.0f]

@implementation customtextField

- (void)setCustomTextFieldText:(NSString*)text{
self.text = text;
}

- (void)setCustomTextFieldAttributes{
NSMutableAttributedString *attString=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.text];
[attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font_italic range:NSMakeRange(0, 75)];
[attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font_boldBlue range:NSMakeRange(76, 21)];
[attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font_boldLargeCentered range:NSMakeRange(98, 20)];}

@end
```

now you can use customTextField as uitextField and can set all property you needed by importing customTextField.h file in your class :

```
    customtextField * txtField = [[customtextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 100, 100, 40)];

    [txtField setCustomTextFieldText:@"your text for textfield"];
    [txtField setCustomTextFieldAttributes];

    [self.view addSubview:txtField];
```

surely it will work for you ..Good Luck

Comment: Thank you, but unless I am not understanding your reply, I think you may have misunderstood my question.  I have the textView class set up. But I want to be able to Bold font, Center the text, and set the font color all within one class that I can use with each [attString... Command

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out how to center the text based on the above format

I created the variable:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc]init] ;
[paragraphStyle setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
```

and used this code to add to the SAME range as text that was already bold.

```
[attString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(161, 35)];
```